# How to get whole document string length for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, mshtml

Currently I have following way to get document size for IE using mshtml API, get html stream and calculate its size:

```
long Size=0;

CComPtr<IStream> spTempStringStream;
CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &spTempStringStream);
if (!!spTempStringStream)
{
    // put the HTML in the Stream
    CComQIPtr<IPersistStreamInit, &IID_IPersistStreamInit> spBrowserStream(m_pHTMLDocument2.GetInterfacePtr());
    if (!!spBrowserStream)
    {
        spBrowserStream->Save(spTempStringStream,false);

        STATSTG stats;
        stats.cbSize.QuadPart = 0; //initializing
        if(!!spTempStringStream)
        {
            spTempStringStream->Stat(&stats,STATFLAG_NONAME);
            ULARGE_INTEGER StreamSize = stats.cbSize;
            Size = (long)StreamSize.QuadPart;
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a problem, if page size is very large, for example, some web pages use base64 string for images, the method can be extremely slow (40 seconds to couple of minutes).

I wonder if there is another way to do this, in C++ or JavaScript. I can inject JavaScript code to page and get its return value.

I know in JavaScript we can calculate length of part of the dom by:

```
document.body.outerHTML.length; // length of body tag

// This can be extremely slow with large page size
// For example, it costs about 40 seconds to run on https://online.skl.com.tw/
```

Is there an efficient way to calculate whole DOM length?

Comment: When the API you're using returns the source code what are your expectations of such thing as image tags? Are you just wanting to remove the HTML tags and return the `src` path of that image? Please give more detail of your expectations/outcome as this question could get bigger and bigger if people assume it's only images/base64 you wish to deal with.

Comment: @NewToJS I don't want to process the DOM. I just want to get the string length of whole document. So I get the whole string first, then get its length.

Comment: Ah so you want to get the source code as a string and return a character count **?** have you checked to see if the time/delay is caused by the API because if so then you can't really do anything about that, all you can do is wait for the API to give you a response before dealing with the content unless that API offers filters to strip content down...

Comment: @NewToJS Yes that is what I want to do. I'm quite sure the delay is caused by API. So I wonder if there is an alternative but **more efficient** way to do the same thing.

Comment: This isn't really something I have tried myself and I am more web-based so my approach to something like this would maybe to use `php` to scrape the content and return it which is no doubt the same as what the API is doing and speed would be down to the hosting of the script performing the scrape... Not really sure what else to suggest other than check the time stamp of the API call to the response to know where the delay occurs.

Comment: @NewToJS I admit this is a rare problem, not many people have faced with this kind of issue... Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155054/discussion-between-newtojs-and-martin-zhai).